# Adafruit Feather 32u4 Bluefruit LE and HC-05 Bluetooth module

Tags: bluetooth, adafruit, hc-05

Is it possible to connect an Adafruit Feather 32u4 Bluefruit LE with an HC-05 Bluetooth module?

I am making a heart rate monitor using an Adafruit Feather, but it is unable to send the data to LABView for processing as it uses BLE. I do not have the means to buy a Bluetooth dongle to work around the issue.

However, I do have an HC-05 Bluetooth module that can be read by VISA on LABView.

Therefore I would like to ask if it is possible to connect my Adafruit Feather to my HC-05 module and send the data through the HC-05 instead of the built-in BLE.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

HC-05 does not support BLE as far as I know but you can use a HM-10 if you can get your hands on one; Its almost about the same cost as a HC-05, maybe a little more;

Comment: I understand that HC-05 does not support BLE. To clarify, is it possible for me to hook up the Adafruit to the HC-05 to connect to my laptop via classic Bluetooth? Thanks!

Comment: You should be definitely able to do that for one simple reason that hc-05 can be connected to any microcontroller board over simple serial communication; I dont have an adafruit feather handy but I have connected hc-05 to a variety of boards including but not limited to the arduinos, esps and stms;